# Getting the child classes name?

Tags: php

I have a simple enumeration class that has some constants defined, but I'd like to have a few static methods provide reflection on the enumeration so a programmer.

Can I ask what keys does this enumeration have?, etc.

I have implemented this and it works as advertised. Great so far, but I'd really like to have a base Enum class, where the implementation for these methods exists and all my Enums can extend this and benefit from it.

Unfortunately when I do that the **CLASS** magic variable returns the base class and messes up the reflection. What I'd love to have is a function to return the child class but any approach that works is fine by me.

Here's the class definition:

```
final class LG_NutritionalValues 
{
   // ENUMERATION 
   const Calories = 1;
   const Fat = 2;
   const Carbohydrates = 3;
   const Etc = 999;

   public static function is_valid_key ( $value ) {
    $reflect = new ReflectionClass ( __CLASS__ );
    return in_array ( $value , array_keys( $reflect->getConstants() ) );
   }
   public static function list_keys() {
    $reflect = new ReflectionClass ( __CLASS__ );
    return array_keys( $reflect->getConstants() );
   }

} // END enum class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since php 5.3 you can use [get_called_class()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php)

Comment: Exactly what I need and I should be able to live with the PHP5.3 constraint. Thanks!